# How to join an irc bot in more than one channel?

Tags: python, bots, irc

I have designed an irc bot using python.

Here is the code for that bot:-

https://github.com/sheeshmohsin/theb0t/blob/sheesh/ekan0ra.py

It is working fine but it is joining in one channel and i have to made it to join in more than one channel. Please give me ideas or the way i can do it.

Comment: It's a simple matter of issuing a `JOIN` for each channel.  The messages you receive will be tagged with the channel name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JOIN command, either multiple times for each channel, or as documented in RFC 1459:

```
self.sendLine("JOIN #channel1,#channel2,#channel3")
```

Optionally you may include keys:

```
self.sendLine("JOIN #channel1,#channel2,#channel3 key1,,key3#")
```

This example demonstrates joining three channels where the second channel has no key.